# Hint for Estimating an Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am currently working through E. V. Shchepin's book *Uppsala Lectures on Calculus: On Euler's Footsteps*, and I've encountered a problem with estimating an infinite sum.

I need a **hint** estimating: S =  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over2^kk}$. This problem appears early in the book in the section on unordered sums.

So far I have bounded S by comparing it to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over2^k}$ = 1 
and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over2^k 2^k}$ = ${1 \over 3}$

I've also tried various groupings of terms such as:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over2^kk}$ = ${1 \over 2}$ ${1 \over 1 }$ + ${1 \over 2^2}$${1 \over 2}$ + ${1 \over 2^3}$${1 \over 3}$ + ${1 \over 2^4}$${1 \over 4}$ +${1 \over 2^5}$${1 \over 5}$ +${1 \over 2^6}$${1 \over 6}$ + ${1 \over 2^7}$${1 \over 7}$ +${1 \over 2^8}$${1 \over 8}$ +$\cdots$

$\ge$ ${1 \over 2}$ ${1 \over 1 }$ + ${1 \over 2^2}$${1 \over 2}$ + (${1 \over 2^3}$${1 \over 4}$ + ${1 \over 2^4}$${1 \over 4}$) + (${1 \over 2^5}$${1 \over 8}$ +${1 \over 2^6}$${1 \over 8}$ + ${1 \over 2^7}$${1 \over 8}$ +${1 \over 2^8}$${1 \over 8}$) +$\cdots$

$=$ ${1 \over 2}$ + ${1 \over 2^3}$+ (${1 \over 2^5}$+ ${1 \over 2^6}$) + (${1 \over 2^8}$ +${1 \over 2^9}$ + ${1 \over 2^{10}}$ +${1 \over 2^{11}}$) +$\cdots$

which is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over2^k}$ with some terms missing.  However, I can't find any pattern to the missing terms.

Any **hints** on how to proceed?

Comment: I guess it's a long shot, but have you already studied power series and/or series of functions?

Comment: I've studied power series in the past from a calculus cookbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have some calculus experience, then recall that $$\int x^{k-1}dx = \frac{x^{k}}{k}+C$$And you should also know that given $x$ such that $|x|<1$ then $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$ Thus integrating both sides with respect to $x$ will get you $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} = \int\frac{1}{1-x}dx$$ By integrating the RHS, playing with the index of the sum and then letting $x=\frac{1}{2}$ you should get your result.

Comment: Yes, the answer seems to be $1 - \ln 2$.

Comment: @MarkFischler Except $$1-\ln(2)<0$$ which doesn't make sense since your series is strictly positive. I think the answer should just be $\ln(2)$, as $$-\ln(1-x) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$
\frac{1}{k} = 1 - \frac{1}{1\cdot 2} -\frac{1}{2\cdot 3} -\frac{1}{3\cdot 4} \cdots \frac{1}{(k-1)k}
$$
Then group terms to get
$$S = 1 \sum \frac{1}{2^k} - \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} \sum \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} + \cdots 
$$
So for example your fifthapproximation will be
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{16} \frac{1}{20} = \frac{111}{160}
$$
which is accurate to three decimal digits.